# Check permutations without modifying original string C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, permutation

I am doing a check whether 2 strings are permutations. I sort the strings then compare each character to each other. However, I think my sorting process also changes the original strings (I am very bad with pointers and passing by reference).

Is there a way to check without modifying the original strings?

I also tried using strcpy but I don't really know how to use it.
I tried this in my check() function:

```
char temp[128];
strcpy(temp, word);
```

Below is my code. I call the areAnagram function from another function like this:

```
void check(char *word, struct Entry *en) { 
   if (areAnagram(en->word, word) == 1) {
        //printf("EW:%s W:%s\n", en->word, word);
        //For example, this should return something like
        // EW:silent W:listen
        //But I got
        // EW:eilnst W:eilnst
   }
}
```

Structure for Entry:

```
typedef struct Entry {
   char *word;
   int len;
   struct Entry *next;
} Entry;
```

Here is the anagram check process:

```
void quickSort(char *arr, int si, int ei);

int areAnagram(char *str1, char *str2)
{
   // Get lenghts of both strings
   int n1 = strlen(str1);
   int n2 = strlen(str2);

   // If lenght of both strings is not same, then they cannot be anagram

   if (n1 != n2) {
      return 0;
   }

   // Sort both strings
   quickSort (str1, 0, n1 - 1);
   quickSort (str2, 0, n2 - 1);

   int i;
   // Compare sorted strings
   for (i = 0; i < n1;  i++) {
      if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
         return 0;
      }
   }

   return 1;
}

void exchange(char *a, char *b)
{
   char temp;
   temp = *a;
   *a   = *b;
   *b   = temp;
}

int partition(char A[], int si, int ei)
{
   char x = A[ei];
   int i = (si - 1);
   int j;

   for (j = si; j <= ei - 1; j++) {
      if(A[j] <= x) {
         i++;
         exchange(&A[i], &A[j]);
      }
   }

   exchange (&A[i + 1], &A[ei]);
   return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(char A[], int si, int ei)
{
   int pi;    /* Partitioning index */
   if(si < ei) {
      pi = partition(A, si, ei);
      quickSort(A, si, pi - 1);
      quickSort(A, pi + 1, ei);
   }
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution would be copy the strings and "mess with" the copies instead of the originals...

Comment: I tried doing something in the check() function like:

char strTemp[128];
strcpy(strTemp, word);

But it gave me an error. I have never use strcpy before so I don't really know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way of checking whether two strings are anagrams.You can create an array to store the count of each character in first string(increment the ASCII value index in the array). Then  traverse second string and decrement the count of each character (ASCII value index in the array). Now check if all elements of array are zero,if yes these are anagrams otherwise not.

int arr[123];
suppose two strings are s1="abba" and s2="baba"

while traversing first string arr[97]=2,arr[98]=2;

while traversing second array arr[97]=0,arr[98]=0;

Now if you traverse the whole array then all elements will be zero.

But if two strings s1="abba" and s2="abac"

while traversing first string arr[97]=2,arr[98]=2;

while traversing second string arr[97]=0,arr[98]=1,arr[99]=-1;

Since all elements of array are not zero so these are not anagrams.

The complexity of above algorithm is O(n).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy using strcpy:

```
char *copy = malloc(strlen(word) + 1); // can use a temporary buffer, but this     allows variable length inputs
strcpy(copy, word);
// use copy as your temporary string

free(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title states that you do not want to modify the original string, however your solution uses Quicksort, which modifies the string. Plus, sorting -- even a fast optimized sort -- is an expensive operation and is not needed for the problem you are trying to solve. You could use a lookup table for speed and it would not modify the original string. You simply create a unique number for each letter and sum the values. Equal sums would constitute an anagram.

```
/* OPTION 1: let the compiler build your table */
static const int A=0x0000001;
static const int B=0x0000002;
static const int C=0x0000004;
/* continue to double for other letters until ... */
static const int Z=0x4000000;

/* OPTION 2: calculate a cheap hash for each letter */
/* Returns 0 for anagram similar to strcmp */
int anagram (const char* word1, const char* word2)
{
    /* strings must be equal length */
    if (strlen(word1) != strlen(word2))
        return -1;

    unsigned long sum1 = 0;
    unsigned long sum2 = 0;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0 ; word1[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        /* use toupper() function here if case insensitive */
        c = toupper(word1[i]);
        sum1 += 1 << (c - 'A');
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; word2[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        /* use toupper() function here if case insensitive */
        c = toupper(word2[i]);
        sum2 += 1 << (c - 'A');
    }
    return (int)(sum1 - sum2); /* ignore overflow */
}
```

The anagram function above is untested and has been written for clarity. You'd need to include the `ctype.h` to convert the case using `toupper()`.

Finally, you could make a copy of one of the strings, traverse the other string calling `strchr()` on each character to find the matching character in the copy. If `strchr()` returns NULL then there is no anagram, otherwise if `strchr()` returns a valid pointer, use it to modify the copy, e.g. set to char value to 0x01, so that you can sum the chars in the modified copy. In this instance, the strings would be anagrams if the sum of all the chars in the modified copy equal the integer length of the comparison string.